# How do you extract keywords based on surrounding characters

Tags: r, text-mining

Trying to extract keywords from a string in R but so far unable to find a solution

Giving the string

```
"erj\"abc\"ejwojeowje \"123\"fjoejfoejf"
```

How to extract the keywords `"abc"` and `"123"` into a character vector?
I tried using `strsplit` based on `\"` but it would also return other unnecessary keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `sub`

```
scan(text=sub('[^"]+"([^"]+)"[^"]+"(\\d+).*',
                           "\\1 \\2", str1), what='')
#[1] "abc" "123"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "erj\"abc\"ejwojeowje \"123\"fjoejfoejf"
```